# Generate a JWT with an X.509 certificate signature in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, jwt, azure-active-directory, x509certificate

I'm trying to get an API access token from Active Directory using certificate authentication as shown here:

[Access token request with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate)

The request needs the **client_assertion** property, which is a JWT created from the certificate with the format and specs mentioned here:

[Assertion format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials#assertion-format)

Is there a way of generating this token in Powershell that is non-interactive as this is part of a release pipeline?

Edit: To make it a little more clear, this C# code using the **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** library is what I'm trying to do in Powershell, specifically the second line:

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

IClientAssertionCertificate assertion = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);

authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, assertion);
```

Comment: Just to clarify : you want to use a certificate to authenticate against azuread to use tge azuread or graph REST api? I might have some (messy) code lying around in my personal archive.

Comment: @bluuf Correct, I want AAD to give me an access token to authenticate requests to other resources, but I don't have the client_secret just the certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code (just tested this, this works for me when I register an app as a web app).

```
<#
    Sample to connect to Graph using a certificate to authenticate

    Prerequisite : ADAL (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll)

#>

# Load the ADAL Assembly
Add-Type -Path "E:\Assemblies\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.4.3.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"

# Settings for the application
$AppID = '<ID OF THE WEB APP>'
$TenantDomain = '<TENANT>'
$LoginUri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'
$Resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
$Certificate = Get-Item 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My\<CERTIFICATE THUMBPRINT>' # This points to my own certificate

# Auth Authority Uri
$Authority = "$LoginUri/$TenantDomain"
# Create the authenticationContext
$Context = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]::new($Authority)
# create the CAC
$CAC = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate]::new($AppID,$Certificate)
# Get the token
$TokenResponse = $Context.AcquireTokenAsync($Resource,$CAC)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 # Sleep for 1 second...

# Token should be present
$TokenResult = $TokenResponse.Result
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you could not use PowerShell to create the JWT.

You could use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to edit each part (header, payload), and then jwt.io will automatically encode it into a JWT for the client_assertion.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sunny, do you have any idea for doing this without user intervention, maybe using azurerm or azuread modules? I thought this would be easier, in c# this are just two lines of code lol

Comment: @Velair, I know,   but even though you use c#, it still needs you manually to create the JWT, if you persist in using client credentials with the certificate. If you don't want the user intervention, you could use the client_secret, it just needs you to create the secret in the registration app.

Comment: See my answer above : this is possible.